# TR as link, its TD as link elsewhere

Tags: javascript

For some really odd reason the tr's `window.location.href` wins against the td's one. If I replace them with alert they show in right order: `td` then `tr` (,when clicked on the right `td`.)

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href='order?order=3'">
    <td>3</td>
    <td onclick="window.location.href='user?user=Bobo'">Eisenreichová Eva</td>
    <td>08. 05. 2013</td>
    <td>Převodem</td>
    <td>Nezaplaceno</td>
    <td>Přijato</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wouldnt the tr win in the end just as your alerts show?

Answer (score 6):

You need to prevent the `click` event from bubbling to the `<tr>`. Use this:

```
onclick="changeLocation(event, 'user?user=Bobo', true);"
```

(you can do the same for the `<tr>` event too)

And declare the function:

```
function changeLocation(e, newURL, noBubble) {
    if (noBubble) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    console.log("Would be navigating to: " + newURL);
    //window.location.href = newURL;
}
```

(in your real code, you'd obviously remove the `console.log` line and uncomment the real part that changes the URL)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yjjVy/

This allows it so if you click on that specific `<td>`, it will "win". If you click anywhere else inside that `<tr>`, it will "win" (since there's no other events conflicting with it).

Answer (score 2):

the td onclick gets triggered first but the tr onclick overwrites the window.location.href

Moving to another page does not stop other javascript from being called.

```
window.location.href='http://www.google.com';
window.location.href='http://www.bing.com';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vH758/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the click bubbles up the dom tree. Therefore the `td`'s onclick is called for the first time, then the click event propagates to the `tr` and that one is executed as well.

To stop the propagation use:

```
<td onclick="window.location.href='user?user=Bobo'; event.stopPropagation();">
```

### What is going on in the background:

**Document structure**:

- document

  - grand parent

    - parent

      - element
    - parent2
  - ...

**Event**: The user clicks on **element**

**Outcome:**

1. All click listeners of **element** are executed *
2. The event starts to bubble
3. All click listeners of **parent** are executed *
4. All click listeners of **grand parent** are executed *
5. All click listeners of **document** are executed *

***The listeners** get the event object, and have the possibility to cancel the bubbling by calling:

- `event.stopPropagation()`: Doesn't let the event propagate to parents, but executes all listeners on current level.
- `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`: Doesn't let the event propagate to parents and no other listeners will be invoked on the same level either

Every layer you can check the click event object for information:

- The currently handling event `event.currentTarget`
- The element that was originally clicked `event.target`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

That's because Javascript reads the last href attribute gave to the location object.
It is imperative, first it executes the td onclick, then the tr one. Since the page hasn't loaded yet, it points to the last href attribute you set.